# Divide a number by what value to reach 1 in a specified number of steps

Tags: divisibility

I would like to divide my number 13255956 by another number over and over again to reach 1 in exactly 255 steps. Through trial and error I managed to find that the number is approximately 1.06.

How might I go about caculating this number precisely?

Sorry if an answer to this aready exists but I wasn't sure of the correct search terms and haven't had luck with my searches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you want to solve $$n^{255}=13255956$$

Taking logs, we get $$255\times \ln(n)=\ln (13255956)\implies \ln(n)=.064313\cdots\implies  $$ $$ n=e^{.064314\cdots}=1.0664\cdots$$

Comment: That's a convoluted way to calculate $n=\sqrt[255]{13255965}\quad$ ;)

Comment: Thanks lulu and saucy.